# how to manage page view in a mobile app?

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile

I want to know some suggestions on how can I manage or design my page for mobile app so that it fits well in both the portrait and landscape orientations. And if some problm occurs, what all methods or events of jquery should I call to fit the page in both the orientations.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit too general for Stack Overflow. Try to bee specific, and preferebly include som code.

Comment: I would read this documentation from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html

Comment: actually my app is displaying perfectly fine in htc and sony ericsson phones but problms are coming in some of the samsung phones.

Comment: The be more specific with your question: What phones are the problem? Provide some screenshots. Give some code. Or a link to the page causing the problems.

Answer (score 0):

I can not give an exact answer to your question. But I advise you to look how decisions for different devices and orientations are made there: [zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)